# DataTempleSelector Not Calling SelectTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I've been trying to get a simple DataTempleSelector going for my WPF Listbox and I've not had any luck. I have a break point set at the SelectTemplate and it's just never getting called. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

C#:

```
public class ListBoxTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultnDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OverrideDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string listboxItem = item as string;
        if (listboxItem == "Apples" || listboxItem == "Oranges")
        {
            return OverrideDataTemplate;
        }

        return DefaultnDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25" Background="Blue"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="OverrideDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25" Background="Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <converters:ListBoxTemplateSelector 
        x:Key="templateSelector"
        DefaultnDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
        OverrideDataTemplate="{StaticResource OverrideDataTemplate}"/>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Apple"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Banannas"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Oranges"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Lemons"/>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hard-coded the UI of the items in the `ListBox` control as `ListBoxItems`

If you want to make use of the `ItemTemplate` you will have to use the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` then your DataTemplate will be applied to each item.

i.e.

```
<ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
</ListBox>
```